# Interface on Data objects

Tags: coding-style, standards

Is there any best practice for not using interface contracts on the data objects.

I have couple of custom controls in my application and i want everyone to maintain a standard for creating controls. For this i created one interface with exposes some standard properties all my controls should implement that interface. I have a check that custom control implements  interface else throw exception.

Is this right way to do keeping best practices in mind or is there any better approach to achieve the same result?